# Why don't 4 indents turn characters to monospace typeface after numbered lines?

Tags: bug, markdown

```
It works fine,
```

1. but...

   not after a numbered line

   ```
   It works fine,
   ```

   1. but...

      not after a numbered line

It doesn't render what suppose to be codes, but does disallow me to submit for being a code-only question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more indents after a numbered list line. (Can never have enough indents)

---

```
It works fine,
```

1. and...

   ```
   it does with more indents after a numbered line
   ```

   ```
   It works fine,
   ```

   1. and...

      ```
      it does with more indents after a numbered line
      ```

Comment: why is that? What is the logic?

Comment: I would assume that lists are effectively indents so you need extra indents in order to say "indent as a part of this list"

Comment: it's bad that indenting 8 spaces cannot be achieved via `ctrl+K`, so you have to indent manually every line